# as it wishes to be seen

Tags: grammar

“Interest in ideology in children's literature arises from a belief that children's literary texts are culturally formative, and of massive importance educationally, intellectually, and socially. Perhaps more than any other texts, they reflect society ***as*** it wishes to be, ***as*** it wishes to be seen, and ***as*** it unconsciously reveals itself to be, at least to writers.”

- source; ‘Language and Control in Children's Literature’ by Murray Knowles, Kirsten Malmkjaer

When I guess the function of the ‘as’ in the underlined part above, I think there might be two possibilities as follows;

(1) One is a subordinating conjunction but one problem in this parse is that there is no complement after ‘be’. Can I think an indefinite pronoun such as ‘something’ is left out?
(2) The other is a quasi relative pronoun like ‘than’, which fills the gap of a complement after ‘be’.

While I’m inclined to (1), which parse would be correct?

Would appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 0):

It is a subordinating conjunction and is used to describe the fact that sb/sth has a particular function and complement after ‘be’ was left out.